# Мета тег увеличения контента

Tags: html, css

Немного странный вопрос, но все же.
Есть сайт с минимальной шириной 1920px. Существует ли мета тег или еще что-нибудь что бы на экранах, к примеру, 2500px контент просто увеличивался, занимая всю ширину и высоту экрана?
Простая центровка не подходит

http://atomr-web.github.io/isuzu/

При разрешении больше, чем 1920х1080 контент остается на месте. Если задать высоту этому блоку 100vh - скроется меню и появится скролл, а его вообще не должно быть (для тачскрин экранов).
Если решения нет с метой, то как хотя бы грамотно отцентровать это?
Через флексы при высоте меньше, чем 1080 контент залезает на хэдер.
Спасибо.

Comment: Без подробностей сложно, конечно. Но все-таки.. чем вам не подходит ширина 100%? И вообще все размеры в процентах

Comment: @Matty сейчас залью на gh pages и отредактирую вопрос

Comment: @Atomrr, это стоило бы сразу сделать, а еще лучше тут код привести

Comment: @Matty добавил.

Comment: @Elena извиняюсь, что сразу не добавил ссыль. куском кода тут не объяснить, к сожалению :\